# When I click the minus image button, all product no. of all item in the cart will minus

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
    protected void minus_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {

        SqlConnection con1 = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myDB"].ConnectionString);
        con1.Open();
        CountTotal();

        foreach (RepeaterItem item in Repeater1.Items)
        {
            String Id = ((Label)item.FindControl("lblId")).Text;
            SqlCommand Command = new SqlCommand("UPDATE [Cart] SET Qty=Qty-1  WHERE ArtId =" + Id, con1);
            

        }
        con1.Close();
        Response.Redirect("/Buyer/Cart.aspx");
    }
```

Comment: You've provided some code. But what actual problem are you facing? What are you trying to do, and what's not working about this code?

Comment: I do the shopping cart. When I add more than 1 item and I want to add the quantity, all item's quantity will add at the same time. I want it just add the quantity of 1 item. minus button also have the same problem.

Comment: Okay - so you're saying this Minus logic is working properly, but you need help implementing the Add functionality?

Comment: This button is working but it will minus all item's quantity. For example, when I add 2 item to cart and I want to decrease the quantity both of the item in my cart will decrease.

Comment: It will only decrement the Qty when the record has a matching ArtId. You haven't described your table structure for us, so it's hard to know whether that's proper or not.